# print individual value from json decoded field

Tags: php, json, symfony, get, echo

how do you print individual values of a json decoded array pls?

```
$monrow = json_encode($monrow);
$monrow= preg_replace("/_DOT_/",  ".", $monrow);
$monrow = json_decode($monrow,true);
```

I have tried the following:

```
var_dump($monrow);  //success, prints the whole array
echo $monrow->name;   //fails with: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
var_dump($monrow->name);  //fails: same error message
var_dump($monrow->properties);  //fails: properties is of type object or hash
```

Thanks

Comment: How your array looks like after json decode ?

Comment: And what about `var_dump($monrow['properties']);`?

Answer (score 2):

json_encode() will translate some object or array to JSON.
json_decode($var,true) will translate it to an ARRAY.
To have a object again use json_decode($var) without the true.

Comment: thanks. i want the value in array. and one field is of object type

Answer (score 1):

Try to get value of array, not a property of object:

```
var_dump($monrow);
echo $monrow['name'];
var_dump($monrow['name']);
```

You can check `$monrow` is array or object:

```
if (is_array($monrow)) {
    echo $monrow['name'];
} elseif (is_object($monrow)) {
    echo $monrow->name;
} else {
    // do something else...
}
```

In your case try to use `foreach`:

```
foreach ($monrow as $row) {
    if (is_array($row)) {
        // do something with array
        echo $row['name']; // for example
    } elseif (is_object($row)) {
        // do something with object
        echo $row->name; // for example
    } else {
        // maybe do something else if you need...
    }
}
```

Commonly after `json_decode` you have array or an instance of `stdClass`.

Comment: Thanks Victor. In my case one of the fields is of type object (so I have strings and objects or hash array fields). How do I display the fields of object type?

Comment: After the JSON decode, _everything_ in your JSON object will come back as an array. You'll have to individually parse objects back into their containers.

Comment: @Kingsley Check is `$monrow` array or object, I updated my answer.

Comment: Why is there an _or_? Both blocks are exactly the same. They are also completely pointless checks.

Comment: @NobleUplift Check second `if` statements, they're different. Yes, they solve same problem, but they aren't the same by code

Comment: thanks guys. my issue is that one of the fields is of type object (is an array). how do i display this?

Comment: @Kingsley Show the result of `var_dump($monrow);` in your question, please.

Comment: var_dump($monrow) is array(7) { ["_id"]=> array(1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "52e0f51f64657635f1000000" } ["campaign_id"]=> int(1111111) ["description"]=> string(4) "test" ["interface_id"]=> int(2121212121) ["mp_commands"]=> string(0) "" ["name"]=> string(9)  "5a158c43-f22a-4380-9} [".marker-target"]=> array(1) { ["d"]=> string(22) "M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z" } } } } } } }

Comment: too long so i cut most of it

Comment: Delete your comment and put it in your question, indented by four spaces.

Comment: Because the op ran `json_decode($monrow,true);`, **the elseif and else will never be hit**. Also, `is_object` and `instanceof` do the exact same thing.

Comment: @Kingsley Try to use `foreach` if you need iterate all elements, check my update

Comment: @Victor my issue is getting the value of only one field called properties. this field is of type Object or Hash. I can get name (string) and description (string)

Comment: @Kingsley, Ok, but I don't see it (`properties`) in your dump of `$monrow`, maybe you better show it? And try to update your answer with dump of `$monrow`, don't post it as comment.

Comment: Checking for `is_array($monrow)` or `is_object($monrow)` is still pointless because **$monrow will always be an array**. Your code will never call `json_decode($monrow, false)`.

Comment: @NubleUplift Ok, but if **$monrow will always be an array** why it fails when OP try to use `$monrow->properties`?

Comment: And my code in `foreach` doesn't pointless. When you use `json_decode($monrow, true)` only *first* level of array will be array,  but *second* level can be array or object

Comment: ... because `$monrow->properties` is a **class property accessor**? `$monrow['properties']` is an array member accessor.

Comment: Also, **wrong**. Wrong wrong wrong. json_decode($json, true) will recursively parse the entire JSON string into an array. There will **not be a single object in the returned array**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where Victor is going with his answer, but this is how you should handle a json_decode:

```
$decodeToArray = true;
$monrow = json_encode($monrow);
$monrow= preg_replace("/_DOT_/",  ".", $monrow);
$monrow = json_decode($monrow, $decodeToArray);

$parsedArray = array();
foreach ($monrow as $key => $value) {
    if ($decodeToArray) {
        if (is_array($monrow[$key]) && $key == 'properties') {
            $obj = new Object();
            foreach ($monrow[$key] as $property => $contents) {
                $obj->$property = $contents;
            }
            $parsedArray[$key] = $obj;
        } else {
            $parsedArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    } else {
        if (is_object($monrow->$key) && $key == 'properties') {
            $obj = new Object();
            foreach ($monrow->$key as $property => $contents) {
                $obj->$property = $contents;
            }
            $parsedArray[$key] = $obj;
        } else {
            $parsedArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Also for Victor, json_decode($json, true) will recursively change the entire JSON string into an array, there will be no objects in the returned array:

```
print_r(json_decode('{"array":[1,2,3],"boolean":true,"null":null,"number":123,"object":{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},"objectArray":[{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"}],"string":"Hello World"}', true));

Array
(
    [array] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [boolean] => 1
    [null] => 
    [number] => 123
    [object] => Array
        (
            [a] => b
            [c] => d
            [e] => f
        )

    [objectArray] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [a] => b
                    [c] => d
                    [e] => f
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [a] => b
                    [c] => d
                    [e] => f
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [a] => b
                    [c] => d
                    [e] => f
                )

        )

    [string] => Hello World
)
```

Comment: It isn't work. You never enter to the `else`, only if `$array` is empty, of couse, if you are meant that `$array` is an array of `json_decode`, otherwise why you do `$array = true;`?

Comment: `$array` was a boolean... Did you even read my code? I renamed it to `$decodeToArray` so that you might better understand my code.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but so better to use `foreach` in this case

Comment: @Kingsley, my code checks for a child object named `properties` and puts it into an array with the other properties of the parent JSON object.